# Cannot create file inside Python on Amazon ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to create a file inside a Django project on Amazon ElasticBeanstalk WebServer Environment. However it gives me a `Permission Denied` error.

Here is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/current/app/foo/boo.py", line 25, in create_file
    input_file = open(input_filename, "w")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'testing.txt'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create file on ElasticBeanstalk, you can, but you shouldn't, you have to use the amazon S3 service for that, with boto3.

But if it's just for a test you can add permisson with the .ebextensions file :

.ebextensions/instance.config

```
container_commands:
  # Permisson on deploy command
  0.0.0.files.chmod.ondeck:
    command: "chmod u+xwr -R /opt/python/ondeck/app"
  # Permisson on run dir
  0.0.1.files.chmod.run:
    command: "chmod u+xwr -R /opt/python/current/app"
```

Comment: Actually, I'm already using S3 for default storage. But I need to process some videos and extract some frames from that videos so I needed some local file creations. Anyway, I have decided to use a `Worker` to handle this operations. Thank you!

Comment: And on the other hand this also didn't solved my problem unfortunately :/ But thank you anyway @Aurelien

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a folder in your app just for that. Than you can `XX_permissions.config` in your `.ebextensions` folder.

```
container_commands:
  01_change_my_folder_permissions:
    command: "mkdir -p /opt/python/current/app/my_folder; chmod 777 -R /opt/python/current/app/my_folder"
```

The command create the folder if doesn't exists and set the permissions. Just verify that your instance got the right permissions connecting directly using the ssh. Run the `eb ssh [name-of-your-env]` and check if the permission are ok:

```
ls -l /opt/python/current/app/
```

You should see your folder with a permission like `drwxrwxrwx` in the list.